# Xamarin.iOS - How to change the label font size dynamically?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I am trying to change the font size based on the iPhone Screen size.

I am setting a font size that looks good on iPhone 6 Plus and once I detect the iPhone and it is not iPhone 6 Plus, I change its size.

I am trying it on the `ViewDidLoad` event:

```
lblLogin.Font.WithSize(17f);
```

But it is not updating the FontSize, I guess "Font.WithSize" is not the path to achieve it, any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WithSize() returns a font reference, it does not modify the existing font

```
lblLogin.Font = lblLogin.Font.WithSize(17f);
```

Also, see this Xamarin [recipe](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/labels/change_the_font/)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the font size of a UILabel, try to use those code, like:

```
//1 Just change size
customLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (18);
//2 Set the font name and size:
customLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica-Bold", 20f);
```

Hope it can help you.